# WSO2 api manager and endpoint HTTPS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-appm

I am trying to connect to an endpoint with wso2 AM and I get the following error:

> INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 303001, ERROR_MESSAGE = Currently , Address endpoint : [ Name : Proyecto2--v1.0.0_APIproductionEndpoint ] [ State : SUSPENDED ]

wso2am is on one server and the endpoint on another, this endpoint is done on node and is HTTPS with self-signed certificate.

I've also tried changing the endpoint to `http://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed` and it works.

If I go directly to the endpoint by postman from my computer it works correctly.

- both environments are development, so I do not have CA certificates
- AM 3.1.0
- the connection to the endpoint is not suspended by timeout, it is immediate (less than 2 second).

I have tried to get data from the wso2 server to the backend server with curl and it worked for me correctly adding "--insecure"

Comment: Is the self-signed certificate trusted and matching the endpoint url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with self-signed certificate. I have uploaded the certificate through wso2 / publisher b

I'm not sure where did you upload the certificate, but in the publisher it's usually the client keypair which is defined, not the endpoint server certificate (I'm not sure about the newest version)

If the self-signed certificate is not trusted (in the **client-truststore.jks**) or the CN doesn't match the URL, the SSL connection will be denied.

You may try

```
#in deployment.toml file.
[transport.passthru_https.sender.parameters]
HostnameVerifier = "AllowAll"
```

In Axis2.xml https sender (if the configuration above is not reflected)

```
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
```

(that should ignore the SSL hostname validation, I do not recommend to do that for prod)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
The first option seems to me to be from the file "wso2server.sh" where that option appears, not in the "deployment.toml".
I added the second one and it has not worked for me either.
I tried to get data from the wso2 server to the backend server with curl and it worked for me by adding "--insecure"